# Unexpected response from a remote method with rest-connector

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, loopback

I try to use Loopback.js with the REST Connector to create an API Gateway.

I get an unexpected response from a remote method with rest-connector, I made this remote method :

```
  // PATCH /act/{id}
  Act.patchActById = async(idAct, act) => {
    const update = act.__data;
    const result = await Act.updateActByRestInAnotherService(idAct, update);
    console.log('result: ', typeof result, result); // -> result:  string 009daef2-c519-45e0-8e4a-743ea74f2a59
    return result;
  };

  Act.remoteMethod('patchActById', {
    http: {
      path: '/:id_act',
      verb: 'PATCH',
    },
    accepts: [{
      arg: 'id_act',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      arg: 'act',
      type: 'Object',
      required: true,
      http: {source: 'body'}
    }],
    returns: {
      arg: 'act',
      type: 'string',
      root: true,
    }
  }
```

I expect this result `"009daef2-c519-45e0-8e4a-743ea74f2a59"`

but I get this kind of object witch is the string I expect put transformed.
Regarding the documentation, I can't understand how and why

```
{
  "0": "0",
  "1": "0",
  "2": "9",
  "3": "d",
  "4": "a",
  "5": "e",
  "6": "f",
  "7": "2",
  "8": "-",
  "9": "c",
  "10": "5",
  "11": "1",
  "12": "9",
  "13": "-",
  "14": "4",
  "15": "5",
  "16": "e",
  "17": "0",
  "18": "-",
  "19": "8",
  "20": "e",
  "21": "4",
  "22": "a",
  "23": "-",
  "24": "7",
  "25": "4",
  "26": "3",
  "27": "e",
  "28": "a",
  "29": "7",
  "30": "4",
  "31": "f",
  "32": "2",
  "33": "a",
  "34": "5",
  "35": "0"
}
```

Thank's a lot for your precious help

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
  Act.patchActById = async(idAct, act, cb) => {
    const update = act.__data;
    const result = await Act.updateActByRestInAnotherService(idAct, update);
    return cb(null,result);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately it's the same :-(